# How can I make Lock Screen widgets work on my Galaxy S3 on Android 4.3?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, lock-screens, 4.3-jelly-bean

When my Galaxy S3 upgraded to 4.3 last night the lock screen lost all its widgets and now immediately turns on to the password entry screen rather then the widget screen where I can slide to unlock or swipe a widget. Because of this I also lost the ability to check the temperature from the lock screen. Does anyone know how to bring back the lock screen widgets for the new update?

I have tried swiping to the left in the upper right hand corner of the screen as I have seen instructed for other phones on 4.3 and have attempted to swipe/tap/hold in other areas of the screen with no luck.  I also checked in all the different setting menu's including going through the lock screen and security settings and there where no options for lock screen widgets (that I saw) and was only able to change from a clock to personal message shown on the screen.

After playing with it some more I was able to get the ability to have widgets on the lock screen and customize them if I set it up to unlock with swipe and no password but if I have any unlock security at all the ability to have lock screen widgets goes away.

Update:
From time to time I will get text messages in my lock window or notifications that I have a lot of them so not sure what is up.

Comment: Have you tried checking the lockscreen/security settings?

Comment: @dotVezz Sorry, I forgot to include that in my original post but I did check both the lock screen and security settings as well as other settings as I poked through the settings menu with no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far I know this is a security "feature" on Android devices that don't let you open personal data through widgets when you set a lock code or a lock pattern. Only works if you don't have no security set.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I was not aware of this and I was used to having the ability to have widgets and some information on the lock screen in 4.1.2. I guess this is something that I will just have to live with for now even though it would be nice to be able to access some basic weather information from the lock screen.

Answer (score -1):

You can still put your own widgets onto the lock screen, but I can't figure out how to get the temp back.

Comment: With security set I have been unable to put widgets on the screen at all other then the clock and a message which where defined in the settings.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an answer to the real question...